# Conventient code for alterning a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

I have a data frame of numbers in 10s from 0 to 100. I would like some concise code for changing each value to a rank, i.e. 100 becomes 1, 90 becomes 2.... and 0 becomes 11.

Is there a nice way of coding this? Here is my code:

```
df[df == 100] = 1
df[df == 90] = 2
...
df[df == 10] = 10
df[df == 0] = 11
```

Comment: Is what I want to reduce, sorry about the typing errors, im new to this

Comment: `order(df, decreasing = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all *dataframe* columns are numbers, then convert it to *matrix*. Then we can do as below:

```
# example data
set.seed(1); x <- matrix(sample(seq(0, 100, 10), 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5)
x
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   20   20   60   70   70
# [2,]   40   90    0   40  100
# [3,]   60  100   20   80   40
# [4,]   90   70   10   50   80

# then convert:
11 - x %/% 10
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    9    9    5    4    4
# [2,]    7    2   11    7    1
# [3,]    5    1    9    3    7
# [4,]    2    4   10    6    3
```

**Note:** This solution works for *dataframe* as well, as long as all columns are class of *numeric*. Matrix is preferred over *dataframe*, when classes of the columns are the same class.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
df <- seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 10)
rank(-df)
[1] 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: The thing is I am working with a dataframe with around 11 columns and 2000 rows, 4 of those columns are string variables, so the code I written ignores these and converts each specific element. The above code works for sequences but not for ranking lots of elements in a mixed data frame. Thank you for all your responses either way.

Answer (score 1):

Using `plyr`:

```
require(plyr)
# It maps values from -> to
mapvalues(a,from = (seq(0,100,10)), to = 11:1)
```

**OR**

Using `rank` (This apporach is only applicable if numbers are distinct):

```
a= seq(0,100,10)
[1]   0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
```

**Code:**

```
rank(-a)
```

**Output:**

```
 [1] 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```